# Recently created event not appearing

Tags: civievent

I created an event for my organization that occurred on July 21st. When I go to "Manage Events", it is not shown in the event list. However, when I search for the event by time period, it once again appears. Why can't I see the event all of the time?

Answer (score 2):

It's assumed that once an event is complete, you're not so interested in it. I also find it a slightly annoying interface, but I get used to doing that search.

On the other hand, for organizations that are hosting lots of events, it's a sensible default.